# Laravel Delete Event Listener

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

A while ago I added all events and listeners related to the auth system, as defined in the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#events), and generated all the listeners. I would now like to use only two listeners and clean up the Listeners folder.

So in `EventServiceProvider` I've commented out what I don't need:

```php
protected $listen = [

    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ],

    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogRegisteredUser',
    ],

    // 'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting' => [
    //     'App\Listeners\LogAuthenticationAttempt',
    // ],

    // 'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Authenticated' => [
    //     'App\Listeners\LogAuthenticated',
    // ],

    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogin',
    ],

    // 'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Failed' => [
    //     'App\Listeners\LogFailedLogin',
    // ],

    // 'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout' => [
    //     'App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogout',
    // ],

    // 'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout' => [
    //     'App\Listeners\LogLockout',
    // ],

    // 'Illuminate\Auth\Events\PasswordReset' => [
    //     'App\Listeners\LogPasswordReset',
    // ],

    // 'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified' => [
    //     'App\Listeners\LogVerifiedUser',
    // ],
];
```

I then delete all Listeners in the app/Listeners folder.

If I then run `php artisan event:generate` I get an error:

> ErrorException  : include(/PATH
>   HERE/vendor/composer/../../app/Listeners/LogRegisteredUser.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

What am I missing?

Comment: try running `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. you may run command

`php artisan clear-compiled`

or,

`composer dump-autoload`

and then run `php artisan event:generate`